# Can we have the ability to filter mod flags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags

Henry Ford taught me that the most efficient way to perform repetitive tasks is to sort them by type.

Can we have the ability to filter mod tags?  Categories could include

- Spam flags
- Comment flags
- Low quality flags
- Not an answer flags
- Exact duplicate flags

The idea being that it is easier to deal with questions of a particular type.  Its not because I want to take care of all the easier flags.  That has nothing to do with it.  I swear.

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of mess up the "sorting by flag importance" thing?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Could still sort by importance within each category.

Comment: @AnnaLear Sure, but why would you handle all flags of a particular type before handling the most important flag of another type?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek If I only have a bit of time, I might not want to look at flags that require investigation, but I could knock off a few spam flags pretty quickly. It's not as good as dealing with the absolute most important flags, but the site's still better off than if I hadn't done anything at all. (Mind you, Programmers doesn't see enough flags at a given time that I'd get tangible benefit from this request either way.)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: If you want to handle the most important flags, then just handle them.  IMHO, "most important" sorting is BS anyhow.  You open up the flag list and see page 1 is full of "not an answer" flags while spam flags are randomly sprinkled throughout the rest of the pages.  Besides, they're *flags*, not nuclear reactor warnings.   They can sit for a few minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There UI can now be filtered (on the right) into various categories, making it easy to:

- focus on more important issues, without getting swamped by close-requests (etc), which the community can *also* deal with via voting
- quickly and easily blitz things that are obvious ("me too" answers and comment flags rarely take much thinking, for example)

I've also added a bit more pattern-recognition on **new** messages (not applied retroactively) to re-categorise some of the "other..." (custom messages) ones more appropriately (exact-duplicate, migration, etc)

Comment: Could you add a similar filtering for the [10k mod tools flag view](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=flags&daterange=today)? This would allow the non-moderator users to close questions quicker, without having to slug through all the not-an-answer flags (where we can't do anything).

Comment: @Paŭlo sure, I can look at that - the data is different, though, so it isn't just a case of turning on a switch

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann When you see a "not an answer" flag, and you think the answer is not really an answer, you can flag the answer for the same reason, or use the "invalid flags" flag, if you think the answer is really an answer.

Comment: @Paŭlo and can I check : on "not an answer", you should have some kind of "agree/disagree" - am I misremembering?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, I can (and I I gained much of my flag weight this way after getting access to the 10k tools) ... but this will not help reducing the moderator queue (and letting the moderators come earlier to my migration flags), while close-votes really help. And there are that many NaA-flags nowadays (okay, today not that many as usual).

Comment: @Paŭlo which is something we are discussing options about internally

Comment: @Marc Yes, I can flag again or flag as "invalid flag". (The latter has the effect that the original flagger gets no flag weight reduction when a moderator finally dismisses it. The former has the effect that this answer moves even further up in the moderator queue, so my migration flag gets even less love.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann It doesn't help reducing the moderator queue, but I think that for the moderators it makes a difference if more users flag a post for the same reason. It also helps you, who don't see anymore that flag when you look at the flag page the next time. `:-)`

Comment: @Paŭlo they are categorized separately (especially now). I do not imagine it will impact your migration, and note that off-topic is something that can already *generally* be done by community voting, rather than raising it as an exception

Comment: My migration flags are migrations to other sites than the default five (usually crypto and TeX). I need moderator intervention there. (The community can close as off-topic, but this will not help moving the post to the right site.)

Comment: Okay, I gotta say I LOVE THIS.  I've even found myself dealing with flags I normally skip over.  And its easier to clear out similar flags than I thought it would be.  NICE!

Comment: So, it appears that all low quality and migration flags have been passed exclusively to 10k mods.  Is that the plan?  If so, its a bit of a pain to try and handle these flags via the 10k mod tools interface...

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ help me out... the "close" dialog is identical on both, right?...?

Comment: @MarcGravell: True, but you can't directly burninate a flag.  You have to flag it as an invalid flag, then go back to the mod tools to clear it out.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ say no more; I know what I'll be doing tomorrow morning, then.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ this is fixed next build, btw

Comment: @MarcGravell: As of UTC 13:39 it appears to be the same.  I switch views, and I can only close or dispute a flag.  I dispute and still have to switch back to remove the flag.  A couple mod buttons to go along with close/dispute would be nice.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ yes; we haven't built yet ;p You're looking for a rev >  2011.11.2.2 (bottom-right)

Comment: Its better, but the UI is rough as heck.  I love how the post titles **GET REALLY BIG AND BOLD ONCE YOU EXPAND THEM**.  I assume you guys will be tweaking it until it reaches the state of perfection that is the mod queue?

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ that wasn't me... waffles was doing some other stuff ...

Comment: @MarcGravell: Pass that buck!

Answer (score 3):

One feature I would like to add to this...

Add the most common action to the list of actions at the bottom of each flag for that particular flag type.

For example, if you sort for "not constructive" flags, then the list of options at the bottom should be something similar to this:

[image: new option list]

- **Close as...** opens the *Why should this question be closed?* dialog
- **Close question** closes the question for the flag reason
- **Dismiss as helpful** dismisses the flag as helpful
- **Dismiss as...** opens the *These flags are…* dialog
- **Other** opens the mod action dialog on the post (I'm not sold on this)

It would be different per filter.  For Spam flags, you might have a "Delete and Notify" button which deletes the question/answer and opens the Moderator Private Message page, or you might have a "Destroy" button which just destroys the user.

Cuts down on the clickies.

Comment: Seems like you could merge the "Close as..." and "Close question" options. The new button would take you to the close dialog, and the reason given in the flag would be preselected. You'd be able to switch to any of the other reasons if you wanted to, of course. (EDIT: you could also simplify further by providing only one button for each flag, "Destroy user." Naturally, that interface would only be for Will.)

Comment: @PopularDemand Do you want to destroy the flagger, the poster, or both?

Comment: can I get your thoughts on the initial cut before we start adding features? (happy to add features that help - simply: often the perceived requirement changes once people get to play with it)

Comment: @Paŭlo the phrase "destroy" only ever applies to users - it is a specific mod action that is particularly delete-happy.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Happily.